# How to use create user in coginto and dynamoDB from .net using aws amplify

Tags: asp.net, react-native, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I'm using aws-amplify in react native application.
and i have a two lambda function

1.PostConfirmation: to create save user to dynamoDB

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
 const params = {
        Item: { __typename: { S: 'User' },createdAt: { S: now.toISOString() },
        updatedAt: { S: now.toISOString() }, etc...},
        TableName: process.env.USER_TABLE
    };
    await ddb.putItem(params).promise();
    };
```

2-PreSignup: to auto confirm user

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
        event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
        if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty('email')) {
            event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;
        }
    return event;
};
```

and in my react component

```
 const { user } = await Auth.signUp({
      username:"test",
      password:"test",
      attributes: {
        email:"test@tt.ca"
      }
    });
  } 
}
```

I am trying to create api route in my backend server .net core to prevent fake account sign-ups.
otherwise move Auth.signUp(..) in server side !
any ideas ?